# What's the fastest speed water from a glacial dam burst could achieve?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, water, speed

I've been watching a lot of Graham Hancock videos of late, thrusting myself deep into the rabbit hole of pseudoarchaeology/alternative archaeology, and I don't really know enough to assess the validity of his claims...

He has claimed that at the end of the last ice age, huge amounts of water (stored in lakes on the 2 mile-high sheet that existed 13 thousand years ago) were unleashed upon the earth in glacial dam bursts causing catastrophic flooding of vast swathes of land.

He states that these catastrophic floods (large enough to induce sea level rise of 30 or 40 feet almost overnight) could travel at speeds of, what I think could be a huge exaggeration, a thousand kilometers per hour.

My question is could water achieve such speeds in quantities of probably billions of cubic meters of water if it were released suddenly from such a dam burst? Is there a maximum speed water can travel across the earth's surface?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730879/).

Comment: 30 to 40 feet overnight is an exaggeration. The entire ice age sea level rise around 8200 years when [Lake Agassiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Agassiz) and  [Lake_Ojibway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Ojibway) (and undoubtedly many other smaller lakes) drained was [only a few metres at most](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.epsl.2011.05.034). The [flow through just one of the drainage pathways](https://www.ualberta.ca/folio/2021/08/massive-ancient-lake-across-prairies-emptied-quickly-enough-to-set-off-an-ice-age-study-suggests.html) took about 9 months, which is not "overnight".

Comment: I did not vote to close this question, but might vote to reopen it if it could be distinguished from the [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/730879/145491). The 1000 kmh estimate probably comes from naively applying Bernoulli's principle to the instant disappearance of a 4 km tall ice dam (which is roughly the maximum glacial depth during the ice ages or currently in Antarctica). This is unrealistic for actual ice-age glacial dam failures, but has me wondering what would happen if the dam were 6 km tall and the naive water velocity would be faster than the speed of sound in air.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that an ice dam breakage unleashed the biggest floods for which geological evidence unambiguously exists, right here in the pacific northwest, during the melting phase of the last ice age 15,000 years ago. See *Spokane floods* or *Bretz floods* for more specific information.

The maximum flow rate of those floods (the ice dam formed and broke over 50 times) can be estimated by knowing the maximum height of the *scour*, and the cross-section of the scour point. These facts yield a flow velocity of about 60 miles per hour for the resulting floods, which created the channeled scablands in central Washington state, the Columbia river gorge, and in the process completely flooded the Willamette valley in Oregon to a depth of several hundred feet.

However, the total flow volume released into the Pacific Ocean by each flood was of order ~tens to hundreds of cubic miles per flood, which would be far too small to result in a measurable increase in the depth of the global ocean.